# document.getElementById("#"); Not Working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace:

```
function checkValue() {
    if (remainingTime < 10) {
        document.getElementById("leading-zero").style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("leading-zero").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

..with this:

```
var leadingZero = document.getElementById("leading-zero");

function checkValue() {
    if (remainingTime < 10) {
        leadingZero.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        leadingZero.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The first block of code works just fine but I don't want to be accessing the DOM everytime checkValue() is called (every half a second). That's why I attempted assigning the object (is it called an object??) to the variable named leadingZero. Why will this not work??

Comment: `The first block of code works just fine` It shouldn't, it should throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: need to run `document.getElementById("leading-zero");` after the element is created

Comment: @CertainPerformance  oops sorry I need to fix that... I was just trying to type the question quickly and messed it up.

Comment: I really don't recommend _typing_ question code. You should copy / paste it from your actual code

Comment: @Phil I was going to.. but I have a heap of unrelated code mixed in as well (which is totally irrelevant).

Comment: Try putting this piece of code at the end of your page

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate leadingZero after document is loaded:

```
var leadingZero;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     leadingZero = document.getElementById("leading-zero");
);

function checkValue() {
    if (remainingTime < 10) {
        leadingZero.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        leadingZero.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Comment: _"I don't want to be accessing the DOM everytime checkValue() is called"_